# g++10 get the c++20 removed features back?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'd like to compile my project along with `grpc` using c++20. The problem is grpc have a dependency on
`abseil-cpp`. And `abseil-cpp` failed to compile because it uses some features removed from c++20, like `std::result_of` and member typedefs of `std::allocator`. When compiled under `MSVC`, its easy to get those features back. But I also need to compile it on linux.

Comment: File a bug with the abseil project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like C++20 support is underway, e.g. removing [result_of](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/pull/705) and [uses of allocator have been fixed](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/issues/722) if you [build in C++20 mode](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/FAQ.md).

I would suggest waiting for grpc / abseil to be updated, perhaps applying those fixes yourself in the mean time.

Comment: You got the question backward.   It is not about features of C++20 that are missing.   It's about using features that were in older C++ standards and removed by C++20.

Comment: @Peter no, I link to the specific examples OP mentions. These things have been removed from the standard because they were *replaced*.

Comment: That is a long way off. Can't tell my boss that I took a risky move and now I need to wait for an update that has no ETA.

Comment: @WeiHsieh the answer is going to be "use a fixed abseil", not "add members to `std::allocator`". If you have to edit abseil / grpc yourself in the mean time, so be it.

Comment: @WeiHsieh: Then you can't use C++20. And you probably shouldn't use it anyway for production code because it's *way* too new. Let compilers mature a bit, and by then, the fixes should be in.

Comment: I don't think libstdc++ removed these...where are you getting your GCC from?

Comment: @T.C. They removed those conditionally dependents on the value of `__cplusplus`. I got GCC by `apt install g++-10` on Ubuntu 20.4

Comment: @WeiHsieh [They most certainly did not](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jjbecP).

Comment: @T.C. You were right. `std::result_of` is still there. But they removed some member typedefs of `std::allocator`